# Show/hide stuff according to checkboxes using CSS: Why this code won´t work?

Tags: css

The user [GGG](https://stackoverflow.com/users/886931/ggg) has kindly gave me an example of how to show and hide stuff using CSS (it´s [here](http://jsfiddle.net/LSF3C/)).

But when I tried to adapt it to my site it failed. Here´s [how I´ve modified it](http://jsfiddle.net/9t59j/3/).

The thing is that each checkbox has a css id, and each one should show different stuff when checked.
The stuff that shows/hides has a css class, and **it´s not adjacent to the checkbox** ([example](http://jsfiddle.net/9t59j/5)).

How can I adapt that code? What I´ve tried didn´t worked so far...

Your insight will be very much appreciated! Thanks!!

Rosamunda

Comment: there's a typo in your html. and what do you mean by not adjacent? your mod has them adjacent

Comment: For starters, your HTML is invalid. There is no class element as you've done here `<class="tipo-uf-134">`. Your `label` tags either need a `for` attribute or need to wrap around an input element. You also have `div` and `p` tags that are not closed properly.

Comment: Thanks, I´ve corrected the errors. Except the label thing that you´ve said, because in my original code, there´s no for attribute, just an empty <label> tag.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/9t59j/6/) updated to use the general sibling selector instead of adjacent sibling selector

```css
    /*styled relative to the label*/
    label {display:block;}
    label ~ input[type="checkbox"] ~ div {display:none; margin-left:1em;}
    label ~ input[type="checkbox"]:checked ~ div {display:inline;}​
```

```html
    <label>Box 1:</label>
    <input class="form-checkbox" id="edit-field-tipos-unidades-disponible-value-131" type="checkbox">
    <div class="tipo-uf-131">Box 1 is checked.</div>
    <br>
    
    <label>Box 2:</label>
    <input class="form-checkbox" id="edit-field-tipos-unidades-disponible-value-134" type="checkbox">
    <div class="tipo-uf-134">Box 2 is checked.</div>
    <br>
    
    <label>Box 3:</label>
    <input class="form-checkbox" id="edit-field-tipos-unidades-disponible-value-130" type="checkbox">
    <div class="tipo-uf-130">Box 3 is checked.</div>​
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! It works, but... how can I point exclusively to those specific checkboxes? Can I point to them using the css code? Thanks again!!!!

Comment: What I cannot understand is how it works, I mean, in the css code there isn´t any reference to the classes! Thanks for your insight!

Comment: it's referencing the element tags directly

Comment: Thanks Joseph! You´ve been very kind :)

Answer (score 1):

It is not working, you must put each answer in a div
like this:

```
<style>
label {display:block;}
label ~ input[type="checkbox"] ~ div {display:none; margin-left:1em;}
label ~ input[type="checkbox"]:checked ~ div {display:inline;}​
</style>
<div>
<label>Box 1:</label>
<input class="form-checkbox" type="checkbox">
<div>Box 1 is checked.</div>
</div>
<div>
<label>Box 2:</label>
<input class="form-checkbox" type="checkbox">
<div>Box 2 is checked.</div>
</div>
<div>
<label>Box 3:</label>
<input class="form-checkbox" type="checkbox">
<div>Box 3 is checked.</div>​
</div>
```